# Почему не появляется картинка?

Tags: c#, wpf

Почему не появляется картинка ?

Так не появляется (MVVM)

```
Image_Source = GetIcon(iconFile);
```

А так появляется, но не обновляется. (без MVVM)

```
Image2.Source = GetIcon(iconFile);
```

XAML

```
<Image x:Name="Image2" Height="100" Width="100" 
    Source="{Binding Image_Source, Mode=TwoWay,                          
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                          
                       />
```

CS

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window ,INotifyPropertyChanged
{


    private ImageSource Image_Source_;
    public ImageSource Image_Source
    {
        get { return Image_Source_; }
        set
        {
            Image_Source_= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ImageSource");
        }       
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new       
            PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    private ImageSource Image_Source_;
    public ImageSource Image_Source
    {
        get { return Image_Source_; }
        set
        {
            Image_Source_= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Image_Source"); // Ошибка была тут
        }       
    }
```

Лично я использую отдельный класс

`GlobalBinding : INotifyPropertyChanged`

В котором находятся нужные мне переменные.  И в каждом Window или UserControl который использует данные переменных нужно привязаться к этому хранилищу таким образом

`this.DataContext = Global.globalBinding;`